# Canvas shadow properties affect all subsequent paths

Tags: javascript, canvas

Canvas shadow properties seem to affect all paths that follow it, even when closing the path that contains those properties. I tried changing the order of things. Ok, placing a path that doesnt require a shadow before the one that does works, but that isnt very reliable work-around. Is there any way to fix this?

Here a simple Jsfiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zrt61283/1/

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// Left
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.shadowColor = 'blue';
ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// Right
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: you can reset with `ctx.shadowBlur = 0;` or `ctx.shadowBlur = null;`

Comment: @maioman please do post your answer since I think that was very helpful. I thought simply closing a path would do the job. I did try what you suggested before but I was never sure if that was the best solution (due to repeating code) until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reset the shadowBlur property with `ctx.shadowBlur = 0;` or `ctx.shadowBlur = null;`

for more info take a look at specs [shadowBlur (canvas2dAPI).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur)

here's an alternative way using save() and restore();

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrt61283/2/)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said doing a reset will work - also you can do .save() which will save the canvas state, you will need to restore as well...

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

// Left
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.shadowColor = 'blue';
ctx.shadowBlur = 30;
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.restore();

// Right
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 75, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.restore();
```

This will basically save the state of the canvas and allow you to take actions within it, then add new things to the canvas and keep them as different pieces.

here is a quick fiddle of this being used - https://jsfiddle.net/e0qm94dn/

Comment: Which method is more professional? I to find your method using save and restore far better but please correct me if im wrong

Comment: @Asperger it depends - the save is nice because it means you're not "resetting" things but rather creating a new transform on the canvas.